# Is it possible to clear the displayed output in ShinyApp using actionButton

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt, action-button

I'm building a shinyApp on *mtcars data*. I got 2 actionButtons **(Go & Clear).**
The **Go button** is for displaying the output on mainPanel whereas the **Clear button** is for clearing that output. 
My Clear button isn't working due to some unforeseen reason. Can somebody please have a look at my codes. I shall be extremely grateful.

```
library(shiny)   
library(DT)     
library(dplyr) 
library(shinythemes) 
library(htmlwidgets) 
library(shinyWidgets) 
library(shinydashboard)

data_table<-mtcars

#ui
ui = fluidPage( 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel (

      uiOutput("cyl_selector"),
      uiOutput("disp_selector"),

      actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Go"),
      actionButton(inputId = "reset", label = "Clear")),


    mainPanel(
           DT::dataTableOutput('mytable') )))



#server
server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$cyl_selector <- renderUI({

    selectInput(inputId = "cyl",
                label = "cyl:", multiple = TRUE,
                choices = c( unique(as.character(data_table$cyl))),
                selected = c('4')) })


  output$disp_selector <- renderUI({

    available <- data_table[c(data_table$cyl %in% input$cyl ), "disp"]  

    selectInput(
      inputId = "disp", 
      label = "disp:",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = c('All',as.character(unique(available))),
      selected = 'All') })


  thedata <- eventReactive(input$go,{

    data_table<-data_table[data_table$cyl %in% input$cyl,]


    if(input$disp != 'All'){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$disp %in% input$disp,]
    }

    data_table
 })


 # thedata <- eventReactive(input$reset,{
 #   data_table<-NULL
 # })


  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable( filter = "top",  rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE,
                   options = list(pageLength = 50, autowidth=FALSE,
                                  dom = 'Brtip'  ),
                   {     
                     thedata()   # Call reactive thedata()
                   })
 })}  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`insertUI()` and `removeUI()` is what you might be looking for.

Removing the element is easier with `removeUI()`:

```
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    removeUI("#mytable")
  })
```

To avoid that you dont delete it permanently you could use `insertUI()`:

```
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    insertUI("#placeholder", "afterEnd", ui = DT::dataTableOutput('mytable'))
  })
```

In order to place the element correctly you can use a placeholder in the `mainPanel()`:

```
mainPanel(
  tags$div(id = "placeholder")
)
```

Then you could remove the dependency of `thedata()` from the input button, since you use the `insertUI()` now. (You should swith to `insertUI()`, because otherwise you cant re-insert the table once its deleted without it,...)

```
  thedata <- reactive({
     ...
  })
```

Full example would read:

```
library(shiny)   
library(DT)     
library(dplyr) 
library(shinythemes) 
library(htmlwidgets) 
library(shinyWidgets) 
library(shinydashboard)

data_table<-mtcars

#ui
ui = fluidPage( 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel (

      uiOutput("cyl_selector"),
      uiOutput("disp_selector"),

      actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Go"),
      actionButton(inputId = "reset", label = "Clear")),


    mainPanel(
      tags$div(id = "placeholder")
    )
  )
)



#server
server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$cyl_selector <- renderUI({

    selectInput(inputId = "cyl",
                label = "cyl:", multiple = TRUE,
                choices = c( unique(as.character(data_table$cyl))),
                selected = c('4')) })


  output$disp_selector <- renderUI({

    available <- data_table[c(data_table$cyl %in% input$cyl ), "disp"]  

    selectInput(
      inputId = "disp", 
      label = "disp:",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = c('All',as.character(unique(available))),
      selected = 'All') })


  thedata <- reactive({
    input$go
    isolate({

      data_table<-data_table[data_table$cyl %in% input$cyl,]


      if(input$disp != 'All'){
        data_table<-data_table[data_table$disp %in% input$disp,]
      }

      return(data_table)
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    removeUI("#mytable")
  })

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    insertUI("#placeholder", "afterEnd", ui = DT::dataTableOutput('mytable'))
  })


  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable( filter = "top",  rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE,
                   options = list(pageLength = 50, autowidth=FALSE,
                                  dom = 'Brtip'  ),
                   {     
                     thedata()   # Call reactive thedata()
                   })
  })}  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, it's a perfect solution. Really grateful :)

Comment: small hint, for min reproducible example seven packages is a lot. :)

Comment: Hi mate, there's a slight problem left in **Go button**. Once go is pressed, and the values of cyl filter are added, the table keeps on changing automatically.. I was hoping that the table would only change when i press Go button. Could you please have a look

Comment: you can use `isolate()` for that, see my edit. If there are additional requirements it would be best to transfer that into a new question. Hope that helps,..

Comment: Thank you so much mate :) Your a genius

Answer (score 1):

Why not inject some javascript? This way, your code is kept virtually unchanged.

Create a `js` file in your shiny folder with the following code (`rmDt.js` in this example):

```
$("#reset").click(function() {
  $(".display.dataTable.no-footer").DataTable().destroy();
  $(".display.dataTable.no-footer").DataTable().clear().draw();    
  $(".display.no-footer").DataTable().destroy();
  $(".display.no-footer").DataTable().clear().draw();    
});
```

Save this file and then inject it in your shiny R script:

```
library(shiny)   
library(DT)     
library(dplyr) 
library(htmlwidgets) 
library(shinyWidgets) 
library(shinydashboard)

data_table<-mtcars

#ui
ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel (
      uiOutput("cyl_selector"),
      uiOutput("disp_selector"),

      actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Go"),
      actionButton(inputId = "reset", label = "Clear"),
      includeScript(path ="rmDt.js") # inject javascript
      ),

    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput('mytable') ))
  )



#server
server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$cyl_selector <- renderUI({

    selectInput(inputId = "cyl",
                label = "cyl:", multiple = TRUE,
                choices = c( unique(as.character(data_table$cyl))),
                selected = c('4')) })


  output$disp_selector <- renderUI({

    available <- data_table[c(data_table$cyl %in% input$cyl ), "disp"]  

    selectInput(
      inputId = "disp", 
      label = "disp:",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = c('All',as.character(unique(available))),
      selected = 'All') })


  thedata <- eventReactive(input$go,{

    data_table<-data_table[data_table$cyl %in% input$cyl,]


    if(input$disp != 'All'){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$disp %in% input$disp,]
    }

    data_table
  })

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable( filter = "top",  rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE,
                   options = list(pageLength = 50, autowidth=FALSE,
                                  dom = 'Brtip'  ),
                   {     
                     thedata()   # Call reactive thedata()
                   })
  })}  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = T))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, it's working for this particular data set, but for the other datatset and complex codings which i got, it doesn't work for some reason. Maybe i'm using shinyjs in those codes. Still i'm really thankful for your efforts :)